# Using UIDatePicker inline style in popover - avoiding keyboard

Tags: uikit, uidatepicker, ios14

I am using the new UIDatePicker 'inline' style in iOS14, and I want to show the picker inside a popover, like I did before in iOS13. I manage to do this fine, but the problem happens when you select the 'time' picker which brings up the keyboard, causing the date picker to get squished.

[image: UIDatePicker with popover]

[image: UIDatePicker in popover with Time selected]

I'm not sure how I can avoid this happening. I've tried:

- scrolling the presenting view controller's tableview to the top, and added a contentInset
- setting a height constraint for the UIDatePicker control
- listening to keyboard notifications, which get triggered but not sure what to do with it

Is there anything else I can try to get it to work correctly? Would love some ideas on potential solutions.

Comment: I'm having the same problem. Seems like a bug - would be worth reporting to Apple if you have not already done so.

Comment: The work-around I used was to put the date picker inside a UITableView; then, listen to keyboard notifications, and check the intersection of the keyboard frame with the tableview, and set the contentOffset of the tableView by that much.

Comment: This was user error on my part. I had been hard-coding the height of the picker at 240. Eliminating the constraint resolved the problem.